# IPad create a programmatically UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

ok, i want to kill my self, entire day with this problem.
i set the tables size, but the problem is that i can not create a cell with the size i want. I will put code.

Acutally the cell size is the defoult one and i cant understand why.

on viewcontroller: i create 10 tables in a scroll

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
NSInteger size=50;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    DynamicTableView *table = [[[DynamicTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size, 50, 254, 600) style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
    [table setDelegate:table];
    [table setDataSource:table];
    [scroll addSubview:table];
    size+=300;
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(5000, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
[super viewDidLoad];
[scroll release];

}
```

on DynamicTableView:

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    FotoCell *cell = (FotoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[FotoCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 90)]   autorelease];
    }
        cell.titLabel.text = @"Meeting on iPhone Development";
        cell.descLabel.text = @"Sat 10:30";
        cell.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"estadio.jpg"];


return cell;
      }
```

on FotoCell:

```
     - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
[super initWithFrame:frame];

self.thumbnail = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,150,90)] autorelease];
self.thumbnail.opaque = YES;

[self.contentView addSubview:self.thumbnail];

self.titLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.thumbnail.frame.size.height * 0.632, self.thumbnail.frame.size.width, self.thumbnail.frame.size.height * 0.37)] autorelease];
self.titLabel.opaque = YES;
self.titLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.4745098 blue:0.29019808 alpha:0.9];
self.titLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.titLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
self.titLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
[self.thumbnail addSubview:self.titLabel];

self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.40784314 blue:0.21568627 alpha:1.0];
self.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.thumbnail.frame] autorelease];
self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = kHorizontalTableSelectedBackgroundColor;

return self;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: that is on table class right? any idea where i can take a look about that?

Comment: Apple Documentation. UITableViewDelegate. Always look through the documentation.

Comment: thx a lot man, u give me the right direction with this. If i can bother u again, i have problem rotating the views. i have in all my clases the method -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation. Its return YES but does not do it. help? :D

Comment: In your overall project settings are you specifying that your app supports all orientations.  You can look at your info.plist file and see what is listed under Supported Interface Orientations.

Comment: on supported interface orientations i have 4 items where i specified the 4 types of orientation. Also implemented the method...im clueless.

Comment: Have you made sure that the device it's self has rotation enabled?

Comment: i was wear. I created a new project and copy all the classes inside of it, now works like a champ. some days ago i got lot of error from nowhere as i didn't change anything and it was working good also. did the same, new project and copy/page and worked fine....wear.