# Create UITableView Cell iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsstring

How can I create a `table view cell` programmatically? I would like to use a string for the text. I have searched and have not found an answer anywhere.

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to dequeue reusable cells from the table view.  As of iOS 5, there is no need to check your cell for `nil` and it will instantiate a cell for you (if needed), provided that you use a cell reuse ID that matches your cell in your XIB or storyboard with the programmatic ID you use in the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"SomeTableCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello!";

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just gone through :[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123430/ipad-create-a-programmatically-uitableviewcell)

Tutorial:[link](http://jainmarket.blogspot.in/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html)

This will definitely help you.